# Backup Exec freezing on inventory and clean jobs

Tags: system-administration, symantec, backupexec

Overall, I need to be able to run backup jobs which are already in place, but are failing whenever run, see my last thread: http://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/1edqsx/ive_been_asked_to_backup_windows_servers_using/[1]

Today, I've been trying to clean the tape drive using a cleaning cartridge which we bought. I inserted the tape, imported it, and marked it as the cleaning slot within backup exec.
Now, however, I'm running into new problems I haven't encountered. First of all, when I try to perform a clean job within Backup Exec, the job starts and makes it to 17%, at which point it returns to 10 percent . It just does this cycle over and over again, never getting above 17%.
Next, I tried inventorying the tape library. I run the job and it begins, but always freezes indefinitely at 30%.
Does anybody have an idea what might be happening, and what I might do to get it working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the firmware on the hardware is up to date. Also be sure that you are using Symantec drivers on the tape drives. You can do this by running the Tapeinst.exe command.

Edit... Also posted on your Redit thread